# It's possible to setup NATS protocol on heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I've seen a lot of documentation and tutorials how to setup HTTPS and Websockets on heroku, but it's possible to setup another protocol like TLS or NATS?

If it's possible how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

> Inbound requests are received by a load balancer that offers SSL
> termination. From here they are passed directly to a set of routers.
>
> The routers are responsible for determining the location of your
> application’s web dynos and forwarding the HTTP request to one of
> these dynos.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#routing

> Not supported
>
> - TCP Routing

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#not-supported

Heroku offers only http/https routing for applications hosted on it.

Comment: Yeah, bad to know that. Just an extra question if I setup my NATS to use WS, theoretically I will be able to connect and use it on heroku right? Since it accepts WS transport.

Comment: Websockets   works on heroku, so probably NATS can work via websockets, but heroku restarts application every 15 minutes (or 30 minutes, as far as i remember) - it can be bad idea to serve state-full application on heroku.

Comment: No worries, I'm thinking to pay a hobby tier who does not restart. Thanks for you help